# Specifying the ranges in scipy.optimize.brute()

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, runtime-error

When I try to minimize a function with [scipy.minimize.brute()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html#scipy.optimize.brute) using the following code:

```
import scipy
scipy.optimize.brute(lambda x: x**2, ranges=(-2,3))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I suppose it has to do with the specification of the range, but I don't see why. The documentation says

> Each component of the ranges tuple must be either a “slice object” or a range tuple of the form (low, high).

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> **Each component** of the ranges tuple must be either a “slice object” or a range tuple of the form (low, high).

So the function expects a tuple of tuples, one of the form `(low, high)` for each dimension. You only have one dimension, so the correct call in your case would be

```
scipy.optimize.brute(lambda x: x**2, ranges=((-2,3),) )
```

Comment: Well, thats more or less by definition, see for example the documentation of [python tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/927/tuple#t=201707280813356182162). Tuples with only one element are created with a trailing comma. Otherwise it would conflict with parentheses in mathematical expressions.

Comment: Ok, now I understand it. Thanks again!

Comment: In fact, a list instead a tuple would also work here, for example `ranges=[[-2,3]]` or any combination of the two.